# JSON RPC request in Golang with Gorilla/rpc

Tags: json, go, rpc, json-rpc

I'm trying to use the `Gorilla/rpc` package to set up a RPC to receive a request and reply with a response (obviously).

First I'm trying with the example provided with `Gorilla/rpc`

Here's my code:

```
type HelloArgs struct {
    Who string
}

type HelloReply struct {
    Message string
}

type HelloService struct{}

func (h *HelloService) Say(r *http.Request, args *HelloArgs, reply *HelloReply) error {
    reply.Message = "Hello, " + args.Who + "!"
    return nil
}

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()

    jsonRPC := rpc.NewServer()
    jsonCodec := json.NewCodec()
    jsonRPC.RegisterCodec(jsonCodec, "application/json")
    jsonRPC.RegisterCodec(jsonCodec, "application/json; charset=UTF-8") // For firefox 11 and other browsers which append the charset=UTF-8
    jsonRPC.RegisterService(new(HelloService), "")
    r.Handle("/api", jsonRPC)

    http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, nil)
}
```

I have a couple of issues:

1. I'm not sure how I would set a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header like I normally would on a `http.ResponseWriter` (with a regular webserver) for cross domain requests, as this doesn't take a `http.ResponseWriter` as an argument.
2. What would I actually send to access the `HelloService.Say` method? I've tried `{ method: "HelloService.Say", params:[{Who: "Me"}]}` but I get `405 (Method Not Allowed)` (not sure if this is because I can't make x-domain requests though?)

Any insight greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try adding quotes to your data: {"method":"HelloService.Say","params":[{"Who":"Me"}]}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **EDITED**: to fix bad use of 'type synonyms'

For number 1:

`Gorilla/rpc/json`'s `CodecRequest.WriteResponse` (which implements `Gorilla/rpc`'s `CodecRequest`) is the **[one place](http://code.google.com/p/gorilla/source/browse/rpc/json/server.go#106)** where the code touches an `http.ResponseWriter`.

This means that we have to have our own implementation of `CodecRequest` which sets the CORS header.

Every `CodecRequest` used by the server is actually generated by a `Codec`; `Codec`s are factories for making `CodecRequests`, to put it another way.

This means that we have to create a `Codec` to generate our `CodecRequest`s that will set CORS headers.

The great thing about Go is that it's really easy to compose this extra behavior!

Try this:

```
package cors_codec
import (
    "Gorilla/rpc"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)
//interface: ain't nobody dope like me I feel so fresh and clean
func CodecWithCors([]string corsDomains, unpimped rpc.Codec) rpc.Codec {
    return corsCodecRequest{corsDomains, unpimped}
}


type corsCodecRequest struct {
    corsDomains []string
    underlyingCodecRequest rpc.CodecRequest
}

//override exactly one method of the underlying anonymous field and delegate to it.
func (ccr corsCodecRequest) WriteResponse(w http.ResponseWriter, reply interface{}, methodErr error) error {
    w.Header().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", strings.join(ccr.corsDomains, " "))
    return ccr.underlyingCodecRequest.WriteResponse(w, reply, error)
}

type corsCodec struct {
    corsDomains []string
    underlyingCodec rpc.Codec
}

//override exactly one method of the underlying anonymous field and delegate to it.
func (cc corsCodec) NewRequest(req *http.Request) rpc.CodecRequest {
  return corsCodecRequest{cc.corsDomains, cc.underlyingCodec.NewRequest(req)}
}
```

That was a fun exercise!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a pretty old question but there is actually an easier way to achieve this.

You can do this thanks to `rs/cors` and `justinas/alice` packages in few lines.

```
func main() {
    chain := alice.New(cors.Default().Handler)

    server := rpc.NewServer()
    server.RegisterCodec(json2.NewCodec(), "application/json")
    server.RegisterService(new(HelloService), "")

    http.Handle("/rpc", chain.Then(server))

    http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil)
}
```